# How to factorize this determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, factoring

> The question is to factorize $$\det\begin{pmatrix}(x^2+1)^2 & (xy+1)^2 & (xz+1)^2  \\ (xy+1)^2 & (y^2+1)^2 & (yz+1)^2 \\ (xz+1)^2 & (yz+1)^2 & (z^2+1)^2  \end{pmatrix}.$$

I have a hint which is considering the factorization of $\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & a & a^2  \\ 1 & b & b^2 \\ 1 & c & c^2  \end{pmatrix}$ where all entries are real numbers.

I don't have any idea how to use the hint. So, I factorize $\det\begin{pmatrix}(x^2+1)^2 & (xy+1)^2 & (xz+1)^2  \\ (xy+1)^2 & (y^2+1)^2 & (yz+1)^2 \\ (xz+1)^2 & (yz+1)^2 & (z^2+1)^2  \end{pmatrix}$ directly and I get the answer which is $2(z-y)^2(z-x)^2(y-x)^2$.

My question is how to use the hint to factorize the given determinant? It is because my method seems very tedious.

Comment: Easy to see that there is a factor $\prod\limits_{cyc}(x-y)^2.$ Also, easy to see that $6\leq\deg\det \leq10$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg but how to factorize the above determinant?

Comment: @Hung218 I think the best way here it's just a full expanding. It's ten minutes of work. I tried.

Comment: I think there is a way to do it with the hint, but I don't see it. What I did notice was that $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 \\ 1 & y & y^2 \\ 1 & z & z^2 \end{pmatrix}^\top \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 \\ 1 & y & y^2 \\ 1 & z & z^2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 + x^2 + x^4 & 1 + xy + (xy)^2 & 1 + xy + (xz)^2 \\ 1 + xy + (xy)^2 & 1 + y^2 + y^4 & 1 + yz + (yz)^2 \\ 1 + xz + (xz)^2 & 1 + yz + (yz)^2 & 1 + z^2 + z^4 \end{pmatrix},$$which is not exactly far from the given matrix.

Comment: @user759562 ohhhhhh, thank you so much, I think I can use the hint to find the answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By calculation (I got this slightly mixed up in my comment),
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2x & x^2 \\ 1 & 2y & y^2 \\ 1 & 2z & z^2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & x^2 \\ 1 & y & y^2 \\ 1 & z & z^2 \end{pmatrix}^\top = \begin{pmatrix} 1 + 2x^2 + x^4 & 1 + 2xy + (xy)^2 & 1 + 2xz + (xz)^2 \\ 1 + 2xy + (xy)^2 & 1 + 2y^2 + y^4 & 1 + 2yz + (yz)^2 \\ 1 + 2xz + (xz)^2 & 1 + 2yz + (yz)^2 & 1 + 2z^2 + z^4 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Using the hint, the first matrix has determinant $2(x - y)(y - z)(x - z)$ and the second matrix has the determinant $(x - y)(y - z)(x - z)$. We can now just multiply these determinants together to get the determinant of the right hand side, which is the matrix in question.